# Lazy Loading using ember table while calling the RestfulService

Tags: ember-table

Using ember-table , can do lazy loading .

Thought it may be issue while calling the restful service.

> A table built using Ember.js that lazily renders rows.Ember Table
>   allows you to handle very large data sets by only rendering the rows
>   that are being displayed. It is written as an ember component with an
>   API that is easy to understand and extend.

Are we still working on it? Could you please let me know. Also, I am not able to open the Ajax implementation site

http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/ajax

Comment: for Reference- https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/issues/167

Comment: Thanks Azirbel for explaination on Lazy Rendering and Lazy Loading concept in the above issues .Seems app.js is not loaded properly in the ajax example properly .
Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input app.js line number 8144

Comment: Seems javascript library site are blocked . It runs fine from my home machine